# How standards-compliant is my polymorph?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion, c++17

Often in code I write there are types that are layout-compatible but are distinct types, but still I'd like to pass them around as if they were the same type. This comes with quite some syntactical overhead, including the necessary casts etc.

I (very) recently thought up a small helper mix-in class, which I dubbed `polymorph`:

```
struct polymorph
{
  template<typename T>
  const T& as() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T&>(*this); }
  template<typename T>
  T& as() { return reinterpret_cast<T&>(*this); }
}
```

A small example "demonstrating" it for the classical "my complex number type is better than yours" situation [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e11615e96c2d97b6)*.
My question is: how robust is this class, and how could I make this more resilient against misuse and/or undefined behaviour. I haven't used it a lot and am kind of hesitant because there are a lot of things that could go terribly wrong.

This class is primarily intended for correspondences such as the one between `_Complex`/`std::complex<double>`/`double[2]`. I'm still thinking of a nice way to extend it to perform useful conversions, and exactly how useful that could be.

*Note I'm not saying this is totally undefined-behaviour free. Hence this question.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @Nathan I explicitly do not want a limited type list.

Comment: As far as `complex<float/double>` <-> `float/double[2]` is concerned, it's well defined because the standard says so. Otherwise, I believe this kind of type-punning is only OK for unions where the member types have common initial sequences.

Comment: @rubenvb Have you looked at `boost::any` or `std::any` then?

Comment: it's indeed not totally undefined-behaviour free. It's totally undefined-behaviour.

Comment: Well, I guess `polymorph{}.as<polymorph>()` is not undefined behavior. But yeah, it's either undefined behavior or pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in violation of [basic.lval]/8, commonly known as the "strict aliasing rule". It says that you may not access an object through a pointer of a type different from the object being pointed to, with a number of exceptions (pointers to base classes, `unsigned char*`, `const`/`volatile` differences, etc). And layout compatibility is not part of that consideration.

So yes, this is UB.

Comment: The OP  wants to know how to extend it to make it more robust, so that the class cannot be used to trigger undefined behavior. He's using it within the context of the strict aliasing rule. He knows that it can be used to voilate it, he is simply asking for it to be extended or for us to give him hints on how to extend it to block uses that would trigger undefined behavior

Comment: @johnathon: As MSalters said in his comment, the *only case* which is not UB is self-conversion, which makes it functionally useless. You are not allowed to pretend that one object is another object, no matter how "compatible" they may seem. Period. The only thing you can do is *convert* the object into another, by initializing a new object in different storage.

Comment: Are you claiming that `struct A{int x;}; A a; ((int*)&a)=0;` is UB?  As is `struct B{int y}; ((B*)&a)->y = 0;`?

Comment: @Yakk: The latter unquestionably violates strict aliasing. You're accessing an object of type `A` through a pointer of type `B`. That's clearly forbidden; there is no exception in [basic.lval]/8 that permits that to work. The first one is less clear-cut, but it seems decidedly dubious.

Comment: So, `struct A{int x;}` is pointer-interconvertible with the `int x` [basic.compound]/4.3.  Access to either object via reinterpret is clearly allowed by [basic.compound]/4.  There is no `B` there, so yes the access through `B*` is illegal (pointer-interconvertibility is a matter of objects, not types).  I'm just pointing out that there are subtle issues there.  Sadly, pointer-interconvertibility permitting pointer-to `double[2]` is not guaranteed with anything except a `struct { double _[2]; }` situation (specifically, `struct { double a, b; }` isn't pointer-interconvertible with `double[2]`)